# Use group policy to force certain security groups to log off remote desktop sessions

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, remote-desktop

I'm having difficulty creating a GPO that will be applied only to certain computers and security groups. Here is what I would like to do.

I have an OU with several computers in them. I would like to apply a GPO that causes remote sessions that have been idle for x amount of time disconnect and for disconnected sessions to log out after y amount of time. I need this to apply to only users in a specific security group.

I have created the GPO and changed the 2 settings in Computer Configuration -> Policies => Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Desktop Session Host -> Session Time Limits.

Next I Link the GPO to my target OU and turn on the Enforce check box. I change the Scope Security Filtering to remove Authenticated Users (because if I don't it gets applied to everyone) and then I add in my security group. I also add in the Domain Computers group (because if I don't it doesn't get applied to anyone)

The problem is that the GPO still gets applied to users that are not part of the security group. If I change the GPO from Computer Configuration to User Configuration then the GPO does not get applied to any users at all.

I have also tried moving the security group to a separate OU and linking the GPO to that OU instead, but that did not work either.

It seems like my configuration should work, but I cannot figure out why it's applying it to users not within the group. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. Computer Configuration settings apply to computers, not users. That's why you needed to add the Domain Computers group to the GPO security filtering... because Computer Configuration settings apply to computers... so the GPO can only affect Computers that are in the OU where the GPO is linked and are in the security group being used as a security filter. As such, the settings will apply to every user that logs onto a computer in the OU where the GPO is linked... because those are Computer Configuration settings.
2. You can't apply Group Policy directly to a group. Group Policies apply to computers and/or users. You can use a group to filter the GPO so that it is only applied to the members of the security group (users or computers).
3. If you want to apply those settings to only a subset of your users then configure those settings under User Configuration... then link the GPO to the OU where your user accounts are... and use Security Filtering to apply the GPO to the subset of users who are members of the security group.

Comment: My apologies, I was using the Security Filtering. Bad terminology on my part, thanks for the clarifications. The key was putting the users in the OU, not the group. That was the missing piece. Thanks!

Comment: You were correct with Security Filtering, it was the rest of it that was off track. Security Filtering can be used to "target" (filter) the GPO to a subset of users in the OU where the GPO is linked. So if you have 100 users in an OU but you only want the GPO linked to that OU to apply to 10 of those users you would add those 10 to a Security group and use that Security group as a filter for the GPO.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned your OU contains several computers, how about the user accounts of your security group? Do they sit in the same OU? User configuration work only if the user account sit in that particular OU if I'm not mistaken.